# Inspect $form from hook API

Tags: nodes, forms, hooks

How can I inspect the $form element from the hook_node_insert(`$node`, `$form`, `$form_value`).
I need to know how it construct.
I try with firephp `(dfb($form, 'form', FirePHP::LOG);)` with no success.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the devel module http://drupal.org/project/devel. In your code call `dpm($form);`

Comment: has the right answer. if you dont want the over head of the devel module the you can use drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($form,true) . "</pre>");

Comment: as @OP has already used firephp, why don't you try Drupal For Firebug module ?

Comment: @AyeshK That's the buggiest module I've ever had the misfortune to install, I'd avoid it if possible :)

Comment: I don't use it much either :) Just suggested as the OP has firephp already.